# How to add parameters in NodeJS' sync-request

Tags: ajax, node.js, post, synchronous

I have tried the following:

```
var request = require('sync-request');

var res = request('POST', 'http://someurl.com', {

  body: {

    'city': 'Dubai'

  }

});
```

But didn't get any parameters on the Server.

Comment: First of all, It looks like you have one too many closing parentheses. Secondly, is the server expecting URL encoded data or json? Third, what is your reasoning for using sync request? It's generally a bad idea to use this in any production environment

Comment: The POST Request is to a PHP Server. I am expecting to pick it with $_POST["city"]

Comment: Alrighty, did you try removing the unnecessary parentheses?

Comment: Sorry for that mistake. I have corrected the code. It doesn't work.

Comment: @MattAltepeter Thanks for your help

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I have **solved** it myself (by modifying the Options as follows):

```
var request = require('sync-request');

var res = request('POST', 'http://someurl.com', {

  headers: {       
    'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
  },

  body: 'city=Dubai'

});
```

It works well.

Comment: this is the 1st time I see that request takes body as string... what if you have many parameters... did you think about converting key/value pairs to string?

Comment: You are a life saver! I had the same issue and this also solved it for me.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a strongly-typed client, you can try out **ts-sync-request**.

NPM: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-sync-request

This library is a wrapper around sync-request.

You can attach a header & make a request like below:

```
import { SyncRequestClient } from 'ts-sync-request/dist'
```

```
let url = "http://someurl.com";

let response = new SyncRequestClient()
                            .addHeader("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
                        .post<string, MyResponseModel>(url, "city=Dubai");
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
request('POST', 'http://someurl.com', {
        json :{
            "key": value
        }
    });
```

On the backend(Django in my case), I just extracted the request body using **request.body**.